# Use alternative to .htaccess file if it exists?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, filenames, httpd.conf

Background: I used to use an environment variable to enable me to differentiate between my dev and production server, using this in .htaccess: -

```
<IfDefine DEV_SERVER>
  # dev server specific stuff here
</IfDefine> 

<IfDefine !DEV_SERVER>
  # production server specific stuff here
</IfDefine>
```

The environment variable "DEV_SERVER" was only ever set on my dev server, and never on production, obviously.

This approach worked a treat until my production server host installed Litespeed as a replacement for Apache. Litespeed doesn't like the above, and ignores everything.

I tried having different versions of .htaccess files for dev and production, but that's messy and dangerous, I like to be able to interchange all files at any time between the two.

My dev server runs Apache 2.4 and I have no plans to change this. I read that you can specify a different filename for .htaccess by putting this in httpd.conf: -

```
AccessFileName .htaccess.dev
```

Which is half way there - now I can have a .htaccess.dev file which only my dev server will use in place of .htaccess. But ideally I would like the dev server to: -

1. use .htaccess if that's all there is
2. use .htaccess.dev if that's all there is
3. use .htaccess.dev if there are both .htaccess and .htaccess.dev present

It does (2) and (3), but unfortunately not (1).

Is there any solution? Any help greatly appreciated, as always!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple files in `AccessFileName` so you can do: `AccessFileName .htaccess.dev .htaccess`

What this will do is to prefer `.htaccess.dev` over `.htaccess` if it exists, and will use `.htaccess` if `.htaccess.dev` doesn't exist.

However, in my opinion you're doing something wrong, if you have to customize your .htaccess per environment :)

Update with working example:

If you put `AccessFileName .htaccess.dev .htaccess` in your Apache configuration (Such as the vhost it will work as it should):

```
# curl -sI http://example.com/test.html | grep "x-htaccess"
x-htaccess: dev
# mv .htaccess.dev htaccess.dev
# curl -sI http://example.com/test.html | grep "x-htaccess"
x-htaccess: default
```

The content of .htaccess is `Header set x-htaccess default` and the content of .htaccess.dev is `Header set x-htaccess dev`.

Comment: I don't think that's the case, as I tried that first (assumed it perhaps worked similar to DirectoryIndex) but it didn't work.


I develop sites on a local server as it's easier, and the setup on this is not always identical to the live one. It has worked this way for me for maybe 12+ years. It's just that there are sometimes minor differences in the way things are done.

Comment: I've updated the post with a working example @JohnA